# Which one sounds more formal: dull vs flat

Tags: meaning

I want to say that the title sounds boring/dull/flat, which means that the title is not special and just mediocre. Which word (among dull vs flat) is more appropriate to use in formal context without sounding like criticizing or too casual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think *flat*, meaning *without emotion or excitement* (as Cambridge Dictionary puts it) can be applied to a title. Moreover, I didn't find any appropriate hits on Google Books.

> After the excitement of the party, **life** seems somewhat flat now.
>
> I thought her **performance** a little flat.
>
> I think the colours in this **painting** are kind of flat.
>
> The past few **days** have seemed comparatively flat and empty.
>
> The party leader delivered a dreadfully flat **speech**.

Regarding *dull* and *boring*, they both can be used along with *title*, meaning *not interesting*.

> In fact, let's be frank, if it's **a really dull title** he may not even read the manuscript.
>
> At first it seemed to me that this meeting had **a very dull title**.
>
> **A seemingly boring title** on first inspection, this game can actually become entertaining.
>
> In fact, it was Karen who inspired me to let go of **a very dull and boring title** and use my grandfather's wonderful banana story.

If you are looking for a synonym for *mediocre*, you could employ *average*, *commonplace*, *ordinary*, *banal*, *trite*.